# How to Change SharePoint Online document Sync Name

Tags: sharepoint-online, sync

I have a site collection with so many subsites and each subsite there is one or more Document library.

some of the staff sync document via OneDrive.
The problem is the default naming for sync folder is "SubSiteName - DocumentLiraryName"

for example, I have a subSite called "Management System" and there is a document library inside which is called "Documents" so when someone syncs this we will have "Management System - Documents" in windows explorer.

Is there any way to change the default name to show only object name? in my example show only "Documents".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When syncing a SharePoint library via OneDrive, it will create a folder and name it as “[Web site title] - [Document library title]”.

It is by default, there is no option to change the name in UI.

If I try to rename it within explorer when its’ status is online, it will popup warning box as shown below:

[image]

Comment: I was thinking something in the background for every user from PowerShell not from windows Explorer